# Parsing the "Sent" line in an email

Tags: python, regex, email, beautifulsoup

I have a folder of ~150 emails, all saved as HTML files (Firefox extensions), and I need to capture the year that is always found on the "Sent" line; as shown in the photo below.

[image]

I tried using RegEx but that failed; it wouldn't print any result at all indicating to me that my RegEx wasn't working. I tried using the `get_payload()` and `message_from_string()` commands from the `email` module but since it's an HTML document those failed. I then tried using BeautifulSoup to capture the entire email and then parse just the "Sent" line, but I failed for reasons unknown. I am not an expert with any of these modules so any and all help would be appreciated.

The relevant code I've tried:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        html_ = open(file_path, 'r').read()
        soup_ = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        pattern = re.compile(r'Sent:/s([/d]{4})')
        txt = html.read()
        dates = pattern.findall(txt)
        if "Sent" in line:
            print("Date:", ''.join(dates))
```

Comment: Use `r'Sent:.*?\b(\d{4})\b'`

Comment: I think that this depends on the HTML formatting of the email ... Also, Is there a way for you to get the raw email data?  Parsing _that_ might be easier since then you just need to find the `Sent` Header...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that worked perfectly thank you so much. I really thought my RegEx skills had improved and I'd get it on my own this time, but I can tell from reading yours that I was pretty far off

Comment: @mgilson that was actually my thought process too, to get the raw data, but I really struggled to succeed doing it that way so I figured I'd ask a question here. Thanks though, the other guy's RegEx was able to solve it for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex (I think the slash is just a typo) does not really match the character between `Sent:` and the year. You may fix the regex as

```
r'Sent:.*?\b(\d{4})\b'
```

Or - to account for the fact that the `Sent` appears at the start of a line:

```
r'(?m)^Sent:.*?\b(\d{4})\b'
```

**Details**:

- `(?m)^` - start of a line
- `Sent:`  - a literal char sequence
- `.*?`  - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\b(\d{4})\b` - a whole word consisting of 4 digits (captured into Group 1 and thus returned as the result of `re.findall`.)